# Apply different styles to same layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

How to apply different styles to customized List View layout item. 
layout is same but I have to apply different coloring

Custom list view layout file.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        cardview:cardElevation="4dp"
        cardview:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        cardview:cardCornerRadius="2dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/options_btn"
                    android:textSize="26dp" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/options_btn"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:text="opts" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <ListView 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:divider="@null"
                    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                    />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I apply different coloring to title and options button, do I have to separate layout file for each styling (don't want to do that because my layout is same for each row) and If If I use @style/myStyle this will become static.
How could I theme ? I have to apply different background styles on cardview and textview coloring and bordering.

Comment: I'm sure there is some convoluted xml way of doing this, but I would just handle it with a single layout and set the color dynamically based on when/where you are using it.

Comment: generate a random color in your adapter dynamically.

Comment: but I have about 10 different styles, that includes cardView background, textview color and border, options button coloring and bordering. if I hard code this will become big. If there is some way of using theme to the parent which contains styling for children as well.

Comment: The problem is styles are setup to allow you to reuse visual attributes across multiple views/layouts. You are asking how to use styles to differentiate them, that isn't what they are made for. You can't dynamically set styles either, so your option is to either create separate layouts or to manage changing things dynamically (from my understanding).